# C# Refine Class Level Type Constraints in Method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class that is a List wrapper. I have a method that I only want to be available when T is a certain type. The compiler is not happy with this. The names have been simplified for brevity but the structure and intent remains:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : List<T> //T can be anything here
{
    ..snip many methods that dont care about the type of T...

    public List<U> Specialize<U>()
        where U : new()
        where T : ISpecializable
    {
        ...some reflection and conversion magic...
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Is there a better way to do this? As it is, the compiler tells me the method does not define T, but if I include it as Specialize<T,U>() then it warns me that T hides the class-level version and that wont work the way I want. I do not want to move the constraint to the class level because I want the other methods to work regardless. I have this "working" right now by doing an explicit type check in the method and throwing an Argument Exception if its wrong, but thats a runtime check and I would prefer the constraint because its a compile-time check.

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: Have you considered defining an extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it with two classes, one has the member the other does not. The one with the method has type constraints the other does not.

```
public class SpecializableCollection<T> : MyCollection<T>
  where T: new(), ISpecializable
{
    ..snip many methods that dont care about the type of T...

    public List<T> Specialize<T>()
    {
        ...some reflection and conversion magic...
    }
}
```

Also you could achieve it with an extension method:

```
public static class SpecializableExtensions
{
    public static List<T> Specialize<T>(this MyCollection<T> specializable)
        where T : new(), ISpecializable
    {
        ...some reflection and conversion magic...
    }
}
```